How do I nmake openssl3.4.0 in win32
I'm trying nmake openssl3.4.0 in win32, but occure some error, "error LNK2001: 无法解析的外部符号 OPENSSL_UplinkTable", could someone give me some suggestions?

libcrypto-shlib-bio_dump.obj : error LNK2001: 无法解析的外部符号 OPENSSL_UplinkTable
libcrypto-shlib-bss_fd.obj : error LNK2001: 无法解析的外部符号 OPENSSL_UplinkTable
libcrypto-shlib-bss_file.obj : error LNK2001: 无法解析的外部符号 OPENSSL_UplinkTable
libcrypto-3.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 个无法解析的外部命令
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “cmd”: 返回代码“0x1”
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “D:\VS2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe”: 返回代码“0x2”
Stop.


This question is similar to: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
